# Is there any similar function of photoshop " Actions .atn" in adobe after effect?

Tags: after-effects, automation

I specifically looking for a plugin or function in After effect that is similar to photoshop actions " .atn" that allow me to record and play sequence of editing i recorded to apply with a one click play like button in Photoshop.

Comment: Can you not just duplicate the sequence and swap out the source? You know, like smart objects.

Comment: You might want to check out Get-Sh*t-Done: http://aescripts.com/get-sh-t-done/

Answer (score 1):

There is no Action function in Adobe After Effects. You would have to write a script to do the sequence for you.

I'm not versed enough to tell you if there's a Plugin or not.